# How to bring through HTML formatting and tags from JSON url into Swift 3

Tags: html, json, swift, swift3

I am building an app which brings data in from a JSON url, that JSON has got html formatting and html tags. How can I pull through the formatting (i.e. bold text etc) through in SWIFT 3. I am dealing with some of the tags by using the following:

```
articleContentValue.text = articleContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

But don't know how to deal with the other formatting issue.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data

Answer (score 0):

If your first instinct is "I'm gonna solve this problem with regex", you will soon have 2 problems on your hand. Regex is not the tool in every case. If you are working with HTML, you need a HTML parser. There is a rudimentary parser built into Cocoa / Cocoa Touch: `NSAttributedString`. It can parse some HTML and give you the plain text:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonString = "{\"html\": \"Welcome to <b>Apple</b>\"}"
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!


do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
    if let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject],
        let htmlString = dict["html"] as? String,
        let htmlData = htmlString.data(using: .utf8),
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(html: htmlData, options: [:], documentAttributes: nil) {
        print(attributedString.string)
    } else {
        print("Can't get the plain text of HTML")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

If your HTML is more complicated, you should start looking at HTML parsing frameworks on CocoaPods or whatever package manager you use.